# Is there a network file system for mainframes (System Z)?

Tags: file, system, mainframe, nfs

Network file systems are offered by Windows and (L)Unix.  Is there one for IBM Mainframes? (Hard to believe not).  Does it offer standard Unix-style access (binary? Ascii? EBCDIC?)
to mainframe data areas?  How are datasets/partitioned data sets treated?
Who configures into Z/OS? How do I find out more about such network file systems for mainframes?

Comment: I'm stunned by the recent negative votes on this, especially considering its age.  Seems like a fine question.  Seems like it has excellent answers, also quite old but quite good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol)) is supported on [System z](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/nfs/).

Answer (score 1):

So is [SMB](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/stgv1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.zos/zos/1.8/Optimization_and_management_capabilities/zOS_V1R8_SMB_setup/player.html)